# Pandas groupby and filter

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, group-by, conditional-statements

I have dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,1,2,2,3,3], 
                   'YEAR' : [2011,2012,2012,2013,2013,2014], 
                   'V': [0,1,1,0,1,0],
                   'C':[00,11,22,33,44,55]})
```

I would like to group by ID, and select the row with V = 0 within each group.

This doesn't seem to work:

```
print(df.groupby(['ID']).filter(lambda x: x['V'] == 0))
```

Got an error:

> TypeError: filter function returned a Series, but expected a scalar bool

How can I use filter to achieve the goal? Thank you.

**EDIT**:
The condition on V may vary for each group, e.g., it could be V==0 for ID 1, V==1 for ID 2, and this info can be available through another DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3], 
                   'V': [0,1,0])
```

So how to do row filtering within each group?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think `groupby` is not necessary, use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) only if need all rows where `V` is `0`:

```
print (df[df.V == 0])
    C  ID  V  YEAR
0   0   1  0  2011
3  33   2  0  2013
5  55   3  0  2014
```

But if need return all groups where is at least one value of column `V` equal `0` add `any`, because [filter](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration) need `True` or `False` for filtering all rows in group:

```
print(df.groupby(['ID']).filter(lambda x: (x['V'] == 0).any())) 
    C  ID  V  YEAR
0   0   1  0  2011
1  11   1  1  2012
2  22   2  1  2012
3  33   2  0  2013
4  44   3  1  2013
5  55   3  0  2014
```

Better for testing is change column for `groupby` - row with `2012` is filter out because no `V==0`:

```
print(df.groupby(['YEAR']).filter(lambda x: (x['V'] == 0).any())) 
    C  ID  V  YEAR
0   0   1  0  2011
3  33   2  0  2013
4  44   3  1  2013
5  55   3  0  2014
```

If performance is important use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print(df[(df['V'] == 0).groupby(df['YEAR']).transform('any')]) 
   ID  YEAR  V   C
0   1  2011  0   0
3   2  2013  0  33
4   3  2013  1  44
5   3  2014  0  55
```

**Detail**:

```
print((df['V'] == 0).groupby(df['YEAR']).transform('any')) 
0     True
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
Name: V, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Can you create new question with reference to this? Do you think at least one value in group is `V` with value by another dataframe `df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3], 
                   'V': [0,1,0])` ? If change it to `df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1,2,3], 
                   'V': [0,1,2])` it dont return last group so output is `{'V': [0, 1, 1, 0], 'ID': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'C': [0, 11, 22, 33], 'YEAR': [2011, 2012, 2012, 2013]}`?

Comment: @jezrael What if I had 2 strings to check `print(df.groupby(['YEAR']).filter(lambda x: (x['V'] == "abc" or x['V'] == "xyz").any())) `

Comment: I think you need `|` instaed `or` (compare arrays) and add `parenthesses` - `print(df.groupby(['YEAR']).filter(lambda x: ((x['V'] == 0) | (x['V'] == 1)).any()))`

Comment: Another solution `print(df.groupby(['YEAR']).filter(lambda x: (x['V'] == 0).any() or (x['V'] == 1)).any())` (not sure if same output), but here compare scalars with `or`

Comment: I tried `dfnew = df.groupby('OrderID').filter(lambda x: ((x['ResponseType']=='MODIFY_ORDER_REJECT') | x['ResponseType']=='CANCEL_ORDER_REJECT')).any() )` basically my intent is to remove all OrderID that contain contained MODIFY_ORDER_REJECT or CANCEL_ORDER_REJECT anywhere in csv. Can talk on chat for a minute maybe. Thanks

Comment: this answer is great!