# how to drop entire group when certain condition met in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to drop all group of data when the certain condition is met!

```
import pandas as pd


raw_data = {'regiment': ['51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st', '51st'], 
            'trucks': ['MAZ-7310', 'MAZ-7310', 'MAZ-7310', 'MAZ-7310', 'Tatra 810', 'Tatra 810', 'Tatra 810', 'Tatra 810', 'ZIS-150', 'ZIS-150', 'ZIS-150', 'ZIS-150'],
            'drivers': ['MAZ', 'MAZ', 'IVE', 'IVE', 'MAN', 'MAN', 'MERC', 'TATA', 'TATA', 'MAN', 'REN', 'TATA'],


            'counts': [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0, 1,2,3,4]}


df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['regiment', 'trucks','drivers','counts']) 

   regiment     trucks drivers  counts
0      51st   MAZ-7310     MAZ       0
1      51st   MAZ-7310     MAZ       0
2      51st   MAZ-7310     IVE       1
3      51st   MAZ-7310     IVE       1
4      51st  Tatra 810     MAN       0
5      51st  Tatra 810     MAN       0
6      51st  Tatra 810    MERC       1
7      51st  Tatra 810    TATA       0
8      51st    ZIS-150    TATA       1
9      51st    ZIS-150     MAN       2
10     51st    ZIS-150     REN       3
11     51st    ZIS-150    TATA       4
```

I'm trying to drop the `MAZ-7310` group when drivers are `MAZ` and `counts == 0`

So I followed this post [Pandas groupby and filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41523270/pandas-groupby-and-filter)

```
df = df.groupby(['regiment','trucks']).filter(lambda x: ~((x['counts'] == 0) & (x['drivers'] == 'MAZ')).all())
```

but it seems that it does not give me the output that I need.

The expected output

```
    regiment     trucks drivers  counts
4      51st  Tatra 810     MAN       0
5      51st  Tatra 810     MAN       0
6      51st  Tatra 810    MERC       1
7      51st  Tatra 810    TATA       0
8      51st    ZIS-150    TATA       1
9      51st    ZIS-150     MAN       2
10     51st    ZIS-150     REN       3
11     51st    ZIS-150    TATA       4
```

How can I get this output ?

thx

Comment: So if one row of the group has driver `MAZ` and counts `0` the whole group should be dropped?

Comment: @Erfan Yes you can say that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First we assign a new column called `m` which is a boolean for the rows where `drivers is MAZ` and `counts is 0`.

Then we use `GroupBy` and get all the groups where `any m is True`.

Then we use boolean indexing to get the opposite with `~`

Methods used:

- [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)
- [`Series.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.0.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html)
- [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html)

```
mask = (df.assign(m=(df['drivers'].eq('MAZ') & ~df['counts']))
          .groupby(['regiment','trucks'])['m'].transform('any')
       )

df[~mask]

   regiment     trucks drivers  counts
4      51st  Tatra 810     MAN       0
5      51st  Tatra 810     MAN       0
6      51st  Tatra 810    MERC       1
7      51st  Tatra 810    TATA       0
8      51st    ZIS-150    TATA       1
9      51st    ZIS-150     MAN       2
10     51st    ZIS-150     REN       3
11     51st    ZIS-150    TATA       4
```

Comment: Wow its more complicated than I thought! Where can I find&study same syntax that you have just posted?

Comment: Besides a more extensive explanation, I made a list of methods I used, plus links to the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

As you desired output, you need to use `any` instead of `all`. Therefore, just change `all` to `any` in your code

```
df_final = df.groupby(['regiment','trucks']).filter(lambda x: ~((x['counts'] ==0) 
                                                    & (x['drivers'] == 'MAZ')).any())

Out[234]:
   regiment     trucks drivers  counts
4      51st  Tatra 810     MAN       0
5      51st  Tatra 810     MAN       0
6      51st  Tatra 810    MERC       1
7      51st  Tatra 810    TATA       0
8      51st    ZIS-150    TATA       1
9      51st    ZIS-150     MAN       2
10     51st    ZIS-150     REN       3
11     51st    ZIS-150    TATA       4
```